# SSL сертификат сайта просит key phrase

Tags: веб-сервер, ssl, debian, nginx

При создании запроса на сертификат SSL указал Key phrase. Теперь при каждой перезагрузке сервера нужно вручную вводить этот ключ. Можно ли настроить автоматический ввод ключа или изменить сертификат (без перевыпуска) таким образом, чтоб этот Key phrase не запрашивался?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Removing a passphrase from an SSL Key](http://mnx.io/blog/removing-a-passphrase-from-an-ssl-key/)